# How to prevent function from running if data error is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request which shows a modal window with a progress bar when the data is computable but if there is an error I would like the error to be returned and the modal window to stay hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {
    var pleaseWait = $('#pleaseWaitDialog');
        showPleaseWait = function () {
            pleaseWait.modal('show');
        };
        hidePleaseWait = function () {
            pleaseWait.modal('hide');
        };
    });

    var $myForm = $('.form')
    $myForm.on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(event.target)
        var formData = new FormData(form[4]);

        $.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        showPleaseWait(); // <---------------  This runs even when view returns error
                        console.log('Percentage uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))
                        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                        $('#progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%');
                    }
                });
                return xhr;
                },
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: new FormData(this),
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success) {
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                }
                if (data.error) {
                    $("#top").html(data.error.title).addClass('form-field-error');
                    $("#div_id_title").removeClass('form-group');
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried moving the `showPleaseWait` function under the `if(data.error)` statement but this doesn't work.

How do I keep the modal window hidden if the response is `(data.error)`?

EDIT:

And this removes the HTML of the page and shows the JSON response instead:

```
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success) {
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                }
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $("#top").html(data.error.title).addClass('form-field-error');
                    $("#div_id_title").removeClass('form-group');
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is the "succes" property of the ajax object.
As shown in the doc, there is a "error" property to handle ajax error, here is the signature :

```
error(xhr,status,error)
```

Use it like you do with the succes property :

```
 $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    showPleaseWait(); // <---------------  This runs even when view returns error
                    console.log('Percentage uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))
                    var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                    $('#progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%');
                }
            });
            return xhr;
            },
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: new FormData(this),
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success) {
                window.location.href = data.url;
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){

            // Do something
        }

    });
```

I hope it solved your issue !

[$.ajax() doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: I used to have the `error: function` but it removes all the HTML and shows only the JSON error in the window.

Comment: can you post the code where you are using the error property ? because it could be the code into that function that remove the HTML and not the property itself.

Comment: Updated OP above

Comment: First, make sure, your "top" id is set to the right node. Secondly, it seems weird to use data.error in the error function, you should used the error passed in paramètres.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "node" but it works in the OP. Can you give an example of what you mean in your "secondly" statement?

Comment: By node, i mean an HTML tag. And instead of using data.error.title to display the error, i would use error.title.

Comment: None of this is the issue.

Comment: The issue here is that the error is a form validation error so it should be handled in the success function. If I knew this I would have wrote it that way. So how do I handle form validation errors without showing the progressbar

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Jquery 3.0 
so try this

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        showPleaseWait(); // <---------------  This runs even when view returns error
                        console.log('Percentage uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))
                        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                        $('#progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%');
                    }
                });
                return xhr;
                },
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: new FormData(this),
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success) {
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                }
                if (data.error) {
                    $("#top").html(data.error.title).addClass('form-field-error');
                    $("#div_id_title").removeClass('form-group');
                }
            },
        })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
$("#top").html(data.error.title).addClass('form-field-error');
                    $("#div_id_title").removeClass('form-group');
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});

Comment: Yes, it is JQuery 3. Though this gives the same problem as above: it shows the JSON error and removes the page.

Comment: check this $("#top").html(data.error.title).addClass('form-field-error');

Comment: What do you mean "check this"? Is there something wrong? It works in the OP

Comment: @DavidAlford This replace top with data.error.title value which may be empty.  check the value ofdata.error.title .generally check  this line means focus here there might be bug.

Comment: Okay, all the punctuation in JS gets really confusing. I fixed it but now it just loads the progress bar just loads and no error message. I will just make another post.

Comment: @DavidAlford great